# psymonitor psypackage problem in R "system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.86589e-16"

Tags: r, parameters, computation

For my Master Thesis i want to do real time monitoring on daily bitcoin data with a total of 2400 observations. When trying to run the PSYmonitor package in R it will give an error message "system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.86589e-16"
Link to R package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psymonitor/index.html

I noticed how in the real time monitoring of bubbles: the S&P500 the authors were using monthly data with an empirical controlled size of 2 years.
These were the R settings that were used for monthly data:

```
y        <- spread$value
obs      <- length(y)
r0       <- 0.01 + 1.8/sqrt(obs)
swindow0 <- floor(r0*obs)
dim      <- obs - swindow0 + 1
IC       <- 2
adflag   <- 6
yr       <- 2
Tb       <- 12*yr + swindow0 - 1
nboot    <- 99
```

I was wondering since I use daily data if I should change any of these parameter settings listed here to make it compatible for daily data? And is the psymonitor package able to work with daily data of 2400 observations?

Hope that somebody can help out!

Michiel

Comment: Your search for an "arbitrage opportunity" already found one: your matrix is not singular, one or more columns are expressable as linear combinations of existing ones.  That is not uncommon -- you can for example not invert for ETFs if you include SPY and several SPY clones.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel So what would i need to change exactly? Im not sure what you imply with your comment